# How to calculate font-size through his parent in SASS?

Tags: css, sass, styles, font-size

I have several heading in my scss file:

```
h1{font-size:18px}
h2{font-size:16px}
h3{font-size:12px}
```

and in my my index.html i've got this:

```
<h1>Heading <span>Secondary text</span></h1>
<h2>Heading <span>Secondary text</span></h2>
<h3>Heading <span>Secondary text</span></h3>
```

I would like to calculate the font-size of the SPAN tag, lats say.. font-size equal minus 2px to the heading that contains him?

Comment: are you trying to adjust the size of font-size inside SPAN tag based on parent DIV tag ? like in for responsive design ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need SASS for it. Just use calc. Something like:

```
.h3 span {
    font-size: calc(100% - 2px);
}
```